# How can I add all dependencies from node_modules to package.json at once?

Tags: node.js, npm

Normally I would execute: `npm install <package_name> --save` for each library/module.

However, is there a way to add all packages that are currently in the `node_modules` folder to the `package.json` dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a built-in way to do that, you can do a small script though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `npm init` to create `package.json` file with all dependencies currently installed, added into it by default. I have npm version 2.11.3.

Earlier versions of npm used to create a `package.json` file without the dependencies. If you are on such a version, run the below command to save the currently installed dependencies into it:

`ls node_modules | xargs npm install --save`

Of course, `ls` & `xargs` will work only if you are on Linux / Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Use : `npm init`

ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

it basically asks you a set of questions and writes out a package.json for you.

Comment: did you mean `npm init`?

Answer (score 1):

The package.json file is used by **NPM** to learn about your node.js project.

Use `npm init` to generate `package.json` files for you!

It comes bundled with **NPM**. Read its documentation here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

Also, there is a standalone tool if you're so inclined (it's made by the maker of **npm**): https://github.com/isaacs/init-package-json